# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Warnings": syntax error in sqlite3 in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I use python 2.7 in Windows7. I want to format the string in sqlite sentence.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Static_Analysis.db')

c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE MAIN
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
   Error_List          CHAR(50),
   Warning_List        CHAR(50),
   Advice_List         CHAR(50),
   Total          CHAR(50),
   Note           CHAR(50));''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ERROR_REPORT
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE WARNING_REPORT
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE ADVICE_REPORT
   (ID INT PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
   NAME           TEXT    NOT NULL);''')


file = open("summary.log",'r')

p1 = re.compile(r"Error")
p2 = re.compile(r"Warning")
p3 = re.compile(r"Advice")

i = 1
m_i = 0
n_i = 0
p_i = 0
for line in file:

m = re.match(p1,line) 
n = re.match(p2,line)  
p = re.match(p3,line)
if m:
    m_i = m_i + 1
    str = line.split(":")
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO MAIN (ID,NAME,Error_List,Note) VALUES (%s, %s, 
%s, E%s)"  % (i, str[1], m_i, m_i))
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO ERROR_REPORT (ID,NAME) VALUES (%s, %s)" % (i, 
str[-1]))
```

When I run this code a create a table and insert data from a file to a table error occurs:

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO MAIN (ID,NAME,Error_List,Note) VALUES (%s, %s, 
%s, E%s)"  % (i, str[1], m_i, m_i))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "Warnings": syntax error
```

How could I fix this error?
I have seen others get this error because he used the same words in his code as the words in sqlite.But in my case, there is no warnings in my code.

Comment: What error and you post it?

Comment: `"INSERT INTO MAIN (ID,NAME,Advice,Note) VALUES ('?', '?',  
      '?', 'A?')"  % i, str[1], p_i, p_i` doesn't do what you think it does. It'll only use `i` for formatting, but then it'll see that the string doesn't contain any format specifiers (those that begin with a percent sign), so you'll get an error.

Comment: @Rakesh  I have updated it and shows the error.